# Вывести произведение всех чисел массива

Tags: массивы

```
double[] mass = new double[5];

mass[0] = 12.4;
mass[1] = 10.9;
mass[2] = 24.8;
mass[3] = 20.1;
mass[4] = 31.9;

double sum = 1;
double x = 1;

for(x = 1; x <= mass.length; x++) {
    sum = sum * x;
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Укажите где я допустил ошибку. Никак не получается. Итог 120 выходит. И откуда это цифра 120

Answer (score 0):

У Вас вычисляется произведение чисел от одного до пяти: `1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120`.

```
int x;
for(x = 0; x < mass.length; x++) {
    sum = sum * mass[x];
}
```